# Training Accuracy is Very Low in A Simple CNN using Theano

Tags: deep-learning, theano, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a CNN using Theano and tried to test my code with a small sample-set of my bigger dataset. I'm trying to categorize a set of 8280 pictures(of 250*250 sizes) into 115 classes and my sample set is a set of 32 pictures of the first two classes(16 pictures from each). The problem I'm experiencing is that from the first epoch, the training loss in NaN and It will not change in the further epochs.

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import os
import time

import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

import lasagne
import re
import cv2
from lasagne.layers import Conv2DLayer, MaxPool2DLayer , DropoutLayer
from lasagne.layers import InputLayer, DenseLayer, batch_norm

def split_list(a_list):
    half = len(a_list)/2
    return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]

def load_dataset(path=''):
    cat_list = []
    filelist = sorted(os.listdir(path))
    trainlist = []
    testlist = []
    tmptrain = []
    tmptest = []
    max_id = 0
    for f in filelist:
        match = re.match(r'C(\d+)([F|G])(\d+)\.PNG', f)
        id = int(match.group(1)) - 1
        max_id = max(max_id,id)
        fg_class = match.group(2)
        fg_id = int(match.group(3))
        if id not in [p[0] for p in cat_list]:
            cat_list.append([id, [], []])
        if fg_class == 'G':
            cat_list[-1][1].append(f)
        else:
            cat_list[-1][2].append(f)
    for f in cat_list:
        id = f[0]
        trainG, testG = split_list(f[1])
        trainF, testF = split_list(f[2])
        tmptrain = tmptrain + [(id, 1, F) for F in trainF] + [(id, 0, G) for G in trainG]  # (Class_id,Forgery,Img)
        tmptest = tmptest + [(id, 1, F) for F in testF] + [(id, 0, F) for F in testG]
    X_train = np.array([cv2.imread(path+f[2],0) for f in tmptrain]).astype(np.int32)
    y_train = np.array([f[0] for f in tmptrain]).astype(np.int32)
    X_test = np.array([cv2.imread(path+f[2],0) for f in tmptest]).astype(np.int32)
    y_test = np.array([f[0] for f in tmptest]).astype(np.int32)
    fg_train = np.array([f[1] for f in tmptrain]).astype(np.int32)
    fg_test = np.array([f[1] for f in tmptest]).astype(np.int32)

    X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train,axis=1).astype(np.int32)
    X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=1).astype(np.int32)

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, fg_train , fg_test


def ExplicitNegativeCorrelation(net,layer='fc2',lr=0.00001):
    for param in lasagne.layers.get_all_params(net[layer]):
        if param.name.startswith('W'):
            W = param
            mean = T.mean(W,0) * lr
            W = W - mean#T.mean(T.mean(W,0))
def ImplicitNegativeCorrelation(MSE,Cross,Hinge):
    mean = T.mean((MSE+Cross+Hinge),axis=0)
    return ((MSE-mean)**2+(Cross-mean)**2+(Hinge-mean)**2)/3

def build_cnn(inputvar,input_shape, trained_weights=None):

    net = {}

    net['input'] = InputLayer(input_shape,input_var=inputvar)
    net['drop_input'] = DropoutLayer(net['input'],p=0.2)
    net['conv1'] = batch_norm(Conv2DLayer(net['input'], num_filters=96, filter_size=11, stride=4, flip_filters=False))#,W=lasagne.init.HeNormal()))
    net['pool1'] = MaxPool2DLayer(net['conv1'], pool_size=3, stride=2)

    net['conv2'] = batch_norm(Conv2DLayer(net['pool1'], num_filters=256, filter_size=5, pad=2, flip_filters=False))#, W=lasagne.init.HeNormal()))
    net['pool2'] = MaxPool2DLayer(net['conv2'], pool_size=3, stride=2)

    net['conv3'] = batch_norm(Conv2DLayer(net['pool2'], num_filters=384, filter_size=3, pad=1, flip_filters=False))#, W=lasagne.init.HeNormal()))
    net['conv4'] = batch_norm(Conv2DLayer(net['conv3'], num_filters=384, filter_size=3, pad=1, flip_filters=False))#, W=lasagne.init.HeNormal()))
    net['conv5'] = batch_norm(Conv2DLayer(net['conv4'], num_filters=256, filter_size=3, pad=1, flip_filters=False))#, W=lasagne.init.HeNormal()))
    net['pool5'] = MaxPool2DLayer(net['conv5'], pool_size=3, stride=2)

    net['fc1'] = batch_norm(DenseLayer(net['pool5'], num_units=2048))
    net['drop_fc1'] = DropoutLayer(net['fc1'])

    net['fc2'] = batch_norm(DenseLayer(net['drop_fc1'], num_units=2048))
    net['fc_class'] = batch_norm(DenseLayer(net['fc2'],num_units=115))

    return net



def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets_class,targets_verif, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets_class)
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets_verif)
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets_class[excerpt], targets_verif[excerpt]





def main(num_epochs=500):

    print("Loading data...")
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, fg_train, fg_test = load_dataset('./signatures/tmp4/')
    X_val, y_val, fg_val = X_train, y_train, fg_train
    print(y_train.shape)

    input_var = T.tensor4('inputs')
    target_var_class = T.ivector('targets')

    network = build_cnn(input_var, (None, 1, 250, 250))

    class_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network['fc_class'])  # ,inputs={network['input']:input_var})
    loss_class = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(class_prediction, target_var_class)

    loss = loss_class.mean()
    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params([network['fc_class']], trainable=True)


    lr = 0.01
    updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(
        loss, params, learning_rate=lr, momentum=0.9)

    test_prediction_class = lasagne.layers.get_output(network['fc_class'], deterministic=True)
    test_loss_class = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(test_prediction_class,
                                                            target_var_class)
    test_loss_class = test_loss_class.mean()
    test_acc_class = T.mean(T.eq(T.argmax(test_prediction_class, axis=1), target_var_class),
                      dtype=theano.config.floatX)


    predict_class = theano.function([input_var], T.argmax(test_prediction_class,axis=1))

    train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var_class], loss, updates=updates)

    val_fn_class = theano.function([input_var, target_var_class], [test_loss_class, test_acc_class])

    print("Starting training...")
    BatchSize = 2
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_err = 0
        train_batches = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_train, y_train,fg_train, BatchSize, shuffle=True):
            inputs, targets_class, targets_verif = batch
            train_err += train_fn(inputs, targets_class)
            #ExplicitNegativeCorrelation(network, layer='fc2',lr=lr/10)
            print(targets_class,predict_class(inputs))
            train_batches += 1

        val_err_class = 0
        val_acc_class = 0

        val_batches = 0
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_val, y_val, fg_val, BatchSize, shuffle=False):
            inputs, targets_class, targets_verif = batch
            err_class, acc_class = val_fn_class(inputs, targets_class)
            val_err_class += err_class
            val_acc_class += acc_class
            val_batches += 1

        print("Epoch {} of {} took {:.3f}s".format(
            epoch + 1, num_epochs, time.time() - start_time))
        print("  training loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(train_err / train_batches))
        print("  Classification loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(val_err_class / val_batches))
        print("  Classification accuracy:\t\t{:.2f} %".format(
            val_acc_class / val_batches * 100))

    test_err_class = 0
    test_acc_class = 0
    test_err_verif = 0
    test_acc_verif = 0
    test_batches = 0
    for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_test, y_test, fg_test, BatchSize, shuffle=False):
        inputs, targets_class, targets_verif = batch
        err_class, acc_class = val_fn_class(inputs, targets_class)
        test_err_class += err_class
        test_acc_class += acc_class
        test_batches += 1
    print("Final results:")
    print("  test loss (Classification):\t\t\t{:.6f}".format(test_err_class / test_batches))
    print("  test accuracy (Classification):\t\t{:.2f} %".format(
        test_acc_class / test_batches * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I've tried to put `lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax` in the DenseLayers but it does fix the NaN issue but the accuracy of the Training model will not be any good, it will be fluctuating between 0 to 25%.(after 50 epochs!).

I have implemented a `load_dataset` function which I think that works correctly (I've tested the function multiple times), and I'm giving the class id of each picture as the target in the loss function. So my inputs and Targets would be like this:

```
Input Shape: (BatchSize, 1, 250, 250) 
Target Shape: (BatchSize, 1) : vector of class ids
```

I've uploaded my sample-set here in [this link](https://ufile.io/i3p67).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we have 4 classes, according to the data, so I changed loading code to reflect it:

```
y_train = np.array([f[0] * 2 + f[1] for f in tmptrain]).astype(np.int32)
y_test = np.array([f[0] * 2 + f[1] for f in tmptest]).astype(np.int32)
```

Number of units in output layer should be equal to the number of classes, so I added an output layer with SoftMax:

```
net['fo_class'] = DenseLayer(net['fc_class'],num_units=4,
                    nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)
```

I suggest removing dropout layer just after inputs – you can compare outcomes with it and without it to make sure of that

Batch size = 2 is too small and learning rate is too high

Here is an example of code with those changes:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import os
import time

import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

import lasagne
import re
import cv2
from lasagne.layers import Conv2DLayer, MaxPool2DLayer , DropoutLayer
from lasagne.layers import InputLayer, DenseLayer

def split_list(a_list):
    half = len(a_list)/2
    return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]

def load_dataset(path=''):
    cat_list = []
    filelist = sorted(os.listdir(path))
    tmptrain = []
    tmptest = []
    max_id = 0
    for f in filelist:
        match = re.match(r'C(\d+)([F|G])(\d+)\.PNG', f)
        id = int(match.group(1)) - 1
        max_id = max(max_id,id)
        fg_class = match.group(2)
        if id not in [p[0] for p in cat_list]:
            cat_list.append([id, [], []])
        if fg_class == 'G':
            cat_list[-1][1].append(f)
        else:
            cat_list[-1][2].append(f)
    for f in cat_list:
        id = f[0]
        trainG, testG = split_list(f[1])
        trainF, testF = split_list(f[2])
        tmptrain = tmptrain + [(id, 1, F) for F in trainF] + [(id, 0, G) for G in trainG]  
        tmptest = tmptest + [(id, 1, F) for F in testF] + [(id, 0, F) for F in testG]
    X_train = np.array([cv2.imread(path+f[2],0) for f in tmptrain]).astype(np.float32)
    y_train = np.array([f[0] * 2 + f[1] for f in tmptrain]).astype(np.int32)
    X_test = np.array([cv2.imread(path+f[2],0) for f in tmptest]).astype(np.float32)
    y_test = np.array([f[0] * 2 + f[1] for f in tmptest]).astype(np.int32)
    fg_train = np.array([f[1] for f in tmptrain]).astype(np.float32)
    fg_test = np.array([f[1] for f in tmptest]).astype(np.float32)

    X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train,axis=1).astype(np.float32)
    X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=1).astype(np.float32)

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, fg_train , fg_test


def ExplicitNegativeCorrelation(net,layer='fc2',lr=0.00001):
    for param in lasagne.layers.get_all_params(net[layer]):
        if param.name.startswith('W'):
            W = param
            mean = T.mean(W,0) * lr
            W = W - mean

def ImplicitNegativeCorrelation(MSE,Cross,Hinge):
    mean = T.mean((MSE+Cross+Hinge),axis=0)
    return ((MSE-mean)**2+(Cross-mean)**2+(Hinge-mean)**2)/3

def build_cnn(inputvar,input_shape, trained_weights=None):

    net = {}

    net['input'] = InputLayer(input_shape,input_var=inputvar)    
    net['conv1'] = Conv2DLayer(net['input'], num_filters=96, filter_size=11, stride=4)
    net['pool1'] = MaxPool2DLayer(net['conv1'], pool_size=3, stride=2)

    net['conv2'] = Conv2DLayer(net['pool1'], num_filters=256, filter_size=5, pad=2)
    net['pool2'] = MaxPool2DLayer(net['conv2'], pool_size=3, stride=2)

    net['conv3'] = Conv2DLayer(net['pool2'], num_filters=384, filter_size=3, pad=1)
    net['conv4'] = Conv2DLayer(net['conv3'], num_filters=384, filter_size=3, pad=1)
    net['conv5'] = Conv2DLayer(net['conv4'], num_filters=256, filter_size=3, pad=1)

    net['pool5'] = MaxPool2DLayer(net['conv5'], pool_size=3, stride=2)

    net['fc1'] = DenseLayer(net['pool5'], num_units=2048)
    net['drop_fc1'] = DropoutLayer(net['fc1'])

    net['fc2'] = DenseLayer(net['drop_fc1'], num_units=2048)    
    net['fc_class'] = DenseLayer(net['fc2'],num_units=115)

    net['fo_class'] = DenseLayer(net['fc_class'],num_units=4,
                        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)
    return net


def iterate_minibatches(inputs, targets_class,targets_verif, batchsize, shuffle=False):
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets_class)
    assert len(inputs) == len(targets_verif)
    if shuffle:
        indices = np.arange(len(inputs))
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for start_idx in range(0, len(inputs) - batchsize + 1, batchsize):
        if shuffle:
            excerpt = indices[start_idx:start_idx + batchsize]
        else:
            excerpt = slice(start_idx, start_idx + batchsize)
        yield inputs[excerpt], targets_class[excerpt], targets_verif[excerpt]

def main(num_epochs=500):

    print("Loading data...")
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, fg_train, fg_test = load_dataset('./signatures/tmp4/')
    X_train /= 255
    X_val, y_val, fg_val = X_train, y_train, fg_train
    print(y_train.shape)    
    check =  X_train[0][0]
    print(check)    

    input_var = T.tensor4('inputs')
    target_var_class = T.ivector('targets')

    network = build_cnn(input_var, (None, 1, 250, 250))

    class_prediction = lasagne.layers.get_output(network['fo_class'])  

    loss_class = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(class_prediction, target_var_class)

    loss = loss_class.mean()
    params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params([network['fo_class']], trainable=True)


    lr = 0.0007
    updates = lasagne.updates.nesterov_momentum(
        loss, params, learning_rate=lr, momentum=0.9)

    test_prediction_class = lasagne.layers.get_output(network['fo_class'], deterministic=True)
    test_loss_class = lasagne.objectives.categorical_crossentropy(test_prediction_class,
                                                            target_var_class)

    test_loss_class = test_loss_class.mean()
    test_acc_class = T.mean(T.eq(T.argmax(test_prediction_class, axis=1), target_var_class),
                      dtype=theano.config.floatX)                     

    predict_class = theano.function([input_var], T.argmax(test_prediction_class,axis=1))

    train_fn = theano.function([input_var, target_var_class], loss, updates=updates)

    val_fn_class = theano.function([input_var, target_var_class], [test_loss_class, test_acc_class])

    print("Starting training...")
    BatchSize = 16
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_err = 0
        train_batches = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_train, y_train,fg_train, BatchSize, shuffle=True):
            inputs, targets_class, targets_verif = batch
            train_err += train_fn(inputs, targets_class)
            print(targets_class,predict_class(inputs))
            train_batches += 1

        val_err_class = 0
        val_acc_class = 0

        val_batches = 0
        for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_val, y_val, fg_val, BatchSize, shuffle=False):
            inputs, targets_class, targets_verif = batch
            err_class, acc_class = val_fn_class(inputs, targets_class)
            val_err_class += err_class
            val_acc_class += acc_class
            val_batches += 1

        print("Epoch {} of {} took {:.3f}s".format(
            epoch + 1, num_epochs, time.time() - start_time))
        print("  training loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(train_err / train_batches))
        print("  Classification loss:\t\t{:.6f}".format(val_err_class / val_batches))
        print("  Classification accuracy:\t\t{:.2f} %".format(
            val_acc_class / val_batches * 100))

    test_err_class = 0
    test_acc_class = 0
    test_batches = 0
    for batch in iterate_minibatches(X_test, y_test, fg_test, BatchSize, shuffle=False):
        inputs, targets_class, targets_verif = batch
        err_class, acc_class = val_fn_class(inputs, targets_class)
        test_err_class += err_class
        test_acc_class += acc_class
        test_batches += 1
    print("Final results:")
    print("  test loss (Classification):\t\t\t{:.6f}".format(test_err_class / test_batches))
    print("  test accuracy (Classification):\t\t{:.2f} %".format(
        test_acc_class / test_batches * 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```